# What does "Error parsing XML: not well-formed" mean?

Tags: parsing, types, element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation=”vertical”
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”fill_parent” >
```

I get these two errors

error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

&

Open quote is expected for attribute "android:orientation" associated with an element type "LinearLayout".

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation=”vertical”
    android:layout_width=”fill_parent”
    android:layout_height=”fill_parent” />

Comment: pay attention on the / before the last character >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you copy and paste that from word? Your quotes look a little funky. Sometimes word will use a different character than the expected " for double quotes. Make sure those are all consistent. Otherwise, the syntax is invalid.

Comment: That's exactly what was wrong, I dragged and dropped from word, retyping it in eclipse fixed the problem, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have "smart quotes" ( not simple " double quotes) around some attributes in your LinearLayout element.

Answer (score 1):

There are many references that explain the differences between *valid* and *well formed* XML documents. A good starting point can be found [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/xml/a/aa071601a.htm). There is also an online [XML Validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp) that you can use to test XML documents.

The validator shows that you have two issues:

1. Some of your attribute values use an invalid quote character:  `”` vs. `"`, and
2. you need to close the `LinearLayout` tag with `/>` instead of just `>`.